# Django queryset filter and get the last item and first item

Tags: django, django-queryset

```
first_order = Order.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).first()
last_order = Order.objects.filter(user_id=request.user).last()
```

I have tried this but both are showing me the same things

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-order_date1',)

 
    STATUS = (
        ('Return', 'Return'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('new order', 'new order'),
        ('hold', 'hold'),

        )


    order_id= models.CharField(max_length=120, blank= True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True , choices=STATUS, default='new order',blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True)
    receiver_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    receiver_address= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    receiver_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    condition= models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    order_date1 = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    delivery_cost = models.IntegerField(default=60,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Probably you have only one Order? Try to create different orders for same user and it will work

Comment: i have tried that its not working.

Comment: because you're showing `username` in `__str__`. so if you filter with the user then it will show the same user name try to print `order_id` or any unique item to identify.

Answer (score 0):

Your results are in fact different, but you display the same info for both of them.

In your class Order, the problem is the definition of `__str__`. Try:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.order_id, self.user.username)
```